# Which strategy for fixing: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '25061-1' for key

Tags: product, import, error

I've a problem with my product import extension that is returned the "**classic" violation** integrity error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '25061-1' for key
>   'UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID'

I'm using Magento `CE 1.7.0.2`.

There are multiple topics about that issue on `stackoverflow`, magento forums with different technical approaches like below:

- Someone recommends to download and use the `dbtools` repairs provided by Magento, **.
- Some are providing db tables list to truncate** "with no major risk".
- An another proposal is to identify with precision the data and remove it from the related db table.

What is the pragmatic way to identify and fix that issue?

Comment: Check your import, be sure to load the stock item, before writing a new one

Comment: The import was working fine for the 5k first articles. Then some articles were removed, and re-create after. I'm working on a local copy of our website and the risk of "simultaneous" creation instruction is guaranteed.

Comment: the problem is, you try to create a stock item with the product_id and stock_id for a product/stock which already exists. This means you have either to delete the old one before or load it, update it and then write it back

Comment: How can I detect the existing product? It is not a problem to remove also the "existing" one and the re-import the two products. Regarding the error, the part '25061-1' mean 25061 should be the entity_id of the existing product? Because I've no product in my catalog with that id...

Comment: check wether you have a stock item with a reference on this product. If this is the case, your foreign key constraints seem to be broken

Comment: I've no result returned for the following query: SELECT * FROM `cataloginventory_stock_item` WHERE `item_id` =25061 OR `product_id` =25061; Where should I look now?

Comment: then I guess your import creates the stock item twice? Be creative. Golden rule: Mysql is never wrong. Or to quote spock "First try all the logical solutions. If they are all disproved, continue with the illogical" Whatever happens, magento tries to create a second stockitem, therefore there must be a first. and if everything happens in an transaction, you can't see it on the outside

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll keep in mind your Golden rule ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error has been found on our import/update script (product->save() was called twice).

Important: no database "cleaning" was required.

I'm happy to have not choose to follow some advice on the web that propose to do  that kind of operations (@fabian, you're golden rule was successfully followed).

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if `cataloginventory_stock_item` table has some orphan rows whos parent records doesn't exist in `catalog_product_entity`

To find out the orphan rows run below query

> SELECT * FROM cataloginventory_stock_item where product_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity)

Once you are done reviewing the data and convinced that you don't need it, just run below query

> DELETE FROM cataloginventory_stock_item where product_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity)